# When running a full node, why does the first inbound node have an unusual IP?

Tags: network

When running `getpeerinfo`, most nodes show a standard `addr` like this:

```
95.121.82.153:8333
```

But the **first inbound connection** has a differently formatted `addr` like this:

```
[2a01:4f8:212:3b1f::2]:32220
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address).  Basically, it's the latest version for formatting/assigning IP addresses.  At some point, we should all be seeing a lot of those...but they've been saying that for years.